# Azure Cloud Service - Creating projects requires Microsoft Azure Tools v2.5 to be installed

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

Using `Visual Studio Community 2013` and `Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.5`.

Trying to add a new project of type `Azure Cloud Service` fails with the error message:

> Creating projects requires Microsoft Azure Tools v2.5 to be installed

Trying to add a new project of type `Azure WebJob` or any other non Azure type works just fine.

Uninstall and re-install of `Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.5` does not work. Neither does `Repair`.

Comment: Are you installing from WebPI? http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing both `Visual Studio Community 2013` and `Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.5` solves the issue.